# UK citizen living in Czech Republic travelling to Singapore via Germany

Tags: uk, schengen, germany, singapore, brexit

I have a UK passport and Czech temporary residency card. I travelled from Prague to Frankfurt on Wednesday and then on Thursday from Frankfurt to Munich then Singapore (the flight Fra-Mun-Sin in business was much cheaper than just Mun-Sin even though it’s the same flight(!?!).

When going through passport control at Munich after scanning my passport the agent asked me when I travelled to Germany and did I have a permit?! I was a little confused but then told her I had a Czech residence permit and seemingly this was fine. She sternly said I should show both next time! If I didn’t have that permit card would I have had a big problem? I know about the EITAS from Nov 2023 but didn’t think there would any issue at the moment. I didn’t want to hang around and ask her to explain further :)

Comment: The residence permit card is required to explain why there is no recent entry stamp. It  was after they searched for the stamp, that the questions were asked. When travelling to other Schengen Countries both your passport and card are required in case of any checks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The permit allows you to stay in the Schengen area during its period of validity.

> If I didn’t have that permit card would I have had a big problem?

Yes.  Without that card, the border officer has no way of knowing that you aren't a visitor.  Without the card, the officer is supposed to determine whether you have complied with the limit of 90 days in every 180-day period allowed for visitors.  Without the card, you would be subject to a fine or worse for overstaying this limit.

The card also exempts you from ETIAS.